# In GAE, I need to refresh to view saved entity just after creating record?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine-python

I am using Google App Engine (boilerplate) for Python. When I create an user, for example, I set redirect_to userlist page in the post method, it does take me to userlist page, but to see the newly created record, I need to refresh the page.
Is there anyway I can view my record without refreshing it? (kinda like turbo-link gem ---)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, at least good enough during my development phase
   :I added time.sleep(0.1) just before the self.redirect('someurl') call.

```
            user.put()
            self.add_message("Changes saved!", 'success')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            return self.redirect_to("users-list", user_id=user_id)
```

What actually happening was that I was giving enough time for my datastore to catch up the new entry.

Note that you have to adjust the time (e.g., >0.1 sec) depending how big/small your db is. For production environment, this might not be a permanent solution!